# Selenuim: Return NoSuchElementException: Message: when using the keyword in robot framework on Safari

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I have some problems with a keyword in robot framework. I would like to use keywords 
`Wait Until Element Is Not Visible` [Ref](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Is%20Not%20Visible) in my code.

And I wrote my keyword like this

```
Have no loading icon
  Set Selenium Timeout  30
  Wait Until Element Is Not Visible   ${loadingIcon}
  Set Selenium Timeout  5
```

When I ran automate in Safari. If this page has to render loading icon, It returns `NoSuchElementException: Message:` in the console. But sometimes this code is working. 
Why it did not wait until 30 sec If page has loading icon.

What I can do my keyword will stable working on safari?

**Environment:**

Safari: 13.1

Robot framework: 3.1.2 (Python 3.7.4)

Comment: Try using `Wait Until Page Contains Element` first.

Comment: I use ```Wait Until Page Does Not Contain Element``` That's work!! Could you explain for me ???

Comment: Are you saying you _literally_ get the exact message `NoSuchElementException: Message`?

Comment: @bkoiiz It's quite likely that your element disappeared from the DOM instead of setting invisible.

Comment: @BryanOakley The console return that message.

Comment: any update on this issue, because i am also getting this same error while i am trying to find element in the web page in safari